# SimpleSamlPhp installation

Tags: php, apache, simplesamlphp

When I try to install simpleSAMLPH I have this message:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /simplesaml/module.php/core/frontpage_welcome.php on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at simplesaml.dev Port 80
```

And I don't understand why their is my file httpd-vhosts.conf :

```
NameVirtualHost simplesaml.dev
<VirtualHost simplesaml.dev>
        ServerName simplesaml.dev
        DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/var/simplesamlphp/www
        Alias /simplesaml /var/simplesamlphp/www
</VirtualHost>
```

I also do all the change in the file config.php of the library simpleSAMLphp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the following configuration to your VirtualHost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost simplesaml.dev>
    ServerName simplesaml.dev
    DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/var/simplesamlphp/www
    Alias /simplesaml /var/simplesamlphp/www

    <Directory />
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I add it after the </VirtualHost> but it don't change anything

Comment: You have to put it inside the VirtualHost definition. I edited my answer.

Comment: Now the message change by not found

Comment: It's cray i just instal it on another computer few month ago

Comment: I think those are different problems. Now that you can access the vhost it trys to find the file you requested but it couldn't found it.

Try to open ```/module.php/core/frontpage_welcome.php``` instead of ```/simplesaml/module.php/core/frontpage_welcome.php```

Comment: I can't do that because the file who include the page is in simplesamlphp library

Comment: Change  
```Alias /simplesaml /var/simplesamlphp/www``` 
to  
```Alias /simplesaml C:/wamp/www/var/simplesamlphp/www```